# Why are metrics in AllenNLP calculated with tensors? Can I define a metric based on strings?

Tags: allennlp

I'm using `AllenNLP` in my project, and I'm confused by the `Metric`: all of the metrics are calculated with tensors, include `bleu` and `rouge`. However sometime I may want to calculate the metric with strings tokenized with white spaces. The built-in metrics are calculated in a token level tokenized by `BertTokenizer`, and it may have a different result because of the difference of tokenization.

Currently I'm converting the tensor to tokens, putting them into a string and calculate my defined `Metric` in `forward`. The code is working now, but I wonder this may not be the right way.

Answer (score 0):

What does not seem to be exactly the AllenNLP way of calculating metrics is getting them in the `forward` call. AllenNLP `train_loop` features a special blueprint function `get_metrics` for this.

However, if you mean that you update your metrics in `forward` and reset them in `get_metrics`, there seems to be no better way to do it.